# Do pulses of lunar waves traverse across the moon?

Tags: astronomy

On the [*Fortean Times* forum](http://forum.forteantimes.com/index.php?threads/people-filming-strange-lunar-waves-on-the-moon.58868/) a user has posted links to a number of conspiracy theorist videos that show strange waves in video images of the Moon.

> Latest conspiracy craze seems to be about "lunar waves" filmed on the
>   moon (from Earth...) They claim it is some form of hologram projected
>   at the moon to cover what is really happening there.

This [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/3LGmF6yVK0Q?t=4m) shows an example.

Are there lunar waves crossing the moon, being picked up in these videos?

Comment: I want to answer this question by talking about ground loops, but I am stymied by the fact it is just my opinion. It will be tricky to prove it. Anyone got any TV experts on hand?

Comment: My gut feeling tells me that the cause of the effect is the equipment. An experiment should be done with different camera/telescope equipment filming all at the SAME TIME.